# About website do I need to download Jquery on my Raspberry pi

Tags: web-server, java

I have a program running with php JavaScript and jQuery scripts.

It is working well on netbeans and my laptop, but it isn't working when uploaded to my Raspberry Pi.

I downloaded PHP, PHP5, MYSQL, etc.. Do I need to download jQuery or Apache as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You do need to install Apache and jQuery as well, because otherwise the PHP and jQuery scripts have nothing to run on. In the case of jQuery, the scripts can't be interpreted by without the necessary libraries.

PHP I believe *can* run without Apache, but it could be a pain to set up. Granted, I have never attempted this myself, but from what I *have* used PHP for, you still need an Apache (or lighttpd, a lighter web server, perfect for the Pi) to display anything `print`ed or `echo`ed from the script.

You probably want to go with `lighttpd` over Apache simply because it's faster and lighter, which is good for the limited resources on the Pi (512MB RAM isn't exactly a world class server.) To install lighttpd on the Pi, check out [this post.](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/light-webserver) It explains the basics of setting up lighttpd as a server and installing PHP5 and MySQL. As for jQuery, setting it up should be just the same as with any other server. Download the software and then link to it in your scripts.

Hope this helps!